I am getting directed to the wrong url while running new Dynamic Web Project on a server
I am starting with learning JSP and servlets and while setup i followed all the steps correctly and added the tomcat server then created a servlet in a new package for a dynamic web project. But whenever I select the file and run it on server this link pops up http://localhost:8080/Project/WEB-INF/classes/myPackage/MyServlet.java which gives the error "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists."
I have no idea what to do and have tried a lot to search on everywhere but can't seem to find anything.It should be directing to http://localhost:8080/Project/MyServlet and when i manually type the url then it works but it never reaches there on its own
this is the web.xml i have :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee" xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_6_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="6.0">
  <display-name>Project</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>MyServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>myPackage.MyServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MyServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>

this is the file :
package myPackage;

import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class MyServlet
 */
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public MyServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}



please help me with this
I just want it to direct to the correct URl http://localhost:8080/Project/MyServlet . I have no idea why i this is happening. I would really appreciate if someone helps me out.

Which version are you using? Can you add download.eclipse.org/releases/2024-06 to your Available Update Sites preference page and Check for Updates from the Help menu to see if it fixes the problem?

The file you selected is not available when you run your application. If you want to include source files then they should be packaged separately.

@RomanC I don't think this is a duplicate, and I maintain the launching functionality in question.

@nitind Don't worry, it is not eclipse problem. The error comes from the Tomcat server, which is not able to find resource.

@RomanC I disagree. The URL Eclipse is trying to launch is incorrectly calculated. As OP indicated, manually using the correct URL does work.

i use the latest version of eclipse, JDk 22.0.1, and tomcat  10.1. Is it something related to deployment assembly. There the source is /src/main/java and the deploy path is WEB-INF/classes i thought it might matter as it is also the thing coming up in the wrong url http://localhost:8080/Project/WEB-INF/classes/myPackage/MyServlet.java . There is also another source  /src/main/webapp which has the deploy path /. Also under the Java resources folder i have a folder with the name of src/main/java this is the folder name and everywhere else i saw the folder was just src. this might be the problem

@nitind You are wrong, the url is correct. At least I don't see any problems with url. But the file requested phisically reside under the WEB-INF/classes. You should read Tomcat policy for accessing content from that location. Everything behind WEB-INF is restricted.

@user25314168 I'm interested in knowing whether the next release will fix your problem (per my first comment)--before I have zero time to do anything else about it.

@RomanC They've correctly declared the servlet class and mapping in the web.xml, so Tomcat should execute the servlet class correctly when requested with the correct URI. The request that's happening, however, is for a source file from a location where it does not and should not exist. The request URI that the IDE is calculating is wrong.

@nitind The url is used to run the file on server. The eclipse is determined the file location after deployment and used a direct access to the file. But it doesn't work in default configuration of Tomcat. You may want to know how to produce the instance of the Tomcat server which has working in the unrestricted mode? It's not covered by this question: it is - off topic. You should read this for explanations

RomanC, that is in fact not how it works. It was a bug. It has been fixed in the upcoming release.
